# How to display days in calendar properly using wrapPanels?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, wrappanel

I am writing a WPF application. I have a `Calendar` and `Buttons` for previous (<), current (today) and next (>) month. My problem is, when I switch a month for next or previous, first day of each month starts always on the same day.

I have a panel where I create other panels. Each panel represents one day. My code should put a label with the number of day in a correct position, but it always starts from the first `WrapPanel`. Where is the problem? Some screenshots below.

[image]
After clicking next Month Button, February should start in Thursday.
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ActivityMonitor
{
/// <summary>
/// Logika interakcji dla klasy CalendarWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CalendarWindow : Window
{
    //lista dni w danym miesiacu
    private List<WrapPanel> daysList = new List<WrapPanel>();

   //aktualna data
    private DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today;

    public CalendarWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayCalendar();
    }

    //metoda wyświetlająca kalendarz
    private void DisplayCalendar()  
    {
        GenerateDayPanel(42);
        //AddDayLabelToWrap(GetFirstDayOfCurrentDate(), GetTotalDaysOfCurrentDate());
        DisplayCurrentDate();
    }

    //metoda 
    private int GetFirstDayOfCurrentDate()
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 1);
        return (int) firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek + 1;
    }

    private int GetTotalDaysOfCurrentDate()
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfCurrentDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 1);
        return firstDayOfCurrentDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;
    }

    private void DisplayCurrentDate()
    {
        labelMonthAndYear.Content = currentDate.ToString("MMMM, yyyy");
        AddDayLabelToWrap(GetFirstDayOfCurrentDate(), GetTotalDaysOfCurrentDate());

    }

    //metoda ustawuająca miesiąc na poprzedni
    private void PreviousMonth()
    {
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-1);
        DisplayCurrentDate();
    }

    //metoda ustawiająca miesiąc na następny
    private void NextMonth()
    {
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(1);
        DisplayCurrentDate();
    }

    //metoda ustawiająca miesiąc na aktualny
    private void Today()
    {
        currentDate = DateTime.Today;
        DisplayCurrentDate();
    }

    //metoda generująca dni tygodnia danego miesiąca
    private void GenerateDayPanel(int totalDays)
    {
        daysPanel.Children.Clear();
        daysList.Clear();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++)
        {
            var wrap = new WrapPanel();
            wrap.Name = $"wrap{i}";
            wrap.ItemWidth = 200;
            wrap.ItemHeight = 100;
            if(i%2 == 0)
            {
                wrap.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
            }
            else
            {
                wrap.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            }
            daysPanel.Children.Add(wrap);
            daysList.Add(wrap);
        }
    }

    //metoda dodająca labele z numerami dni miesiąca
    private void AddDayLabelToWrap(int startDayAtPanel, int totalDaysInMonth)
    {
        foreach (WrapPanel wrap in daysList)
        {
            wrap.Children.Clear();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalDaysInMonth; i++)
        {
            var lab = new Label();
            lab.Name = $"lblDay{i}";
            lab.Content = i;
            lab.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            daysList[(i - 1) + (startDayAtPanel - 1)].Children.Add(lab);
        }
    }

    
    private void ButtonPrevMonth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PreviousMonth();
    }

    private void ButtonNextMonth_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NextMonth();
    }

    private void ButtonToday_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Today();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: In GenerateDayPanel you need to add three blank WrapPanel. to daysList.  So you need to add three items using daysList.Add(wrap);

Comment: @mateuszj Please add the code for your xaml as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made the sample you need and put it on the GitHub.

> Here.
> https://github.com/ncoresoftsource/stackoverflowsample/tree/main/src/answers/custom-calendar-app

This is not as simple as I thought. And like other people's advice, writing the UI in the behind code is not a good way in the long run, so I hope you study this sample source code that I made for you!

Just point!

- Using ListBox

  ```cs
  public class CalendarBox : ListBox
  {

  }
  ```
- Style & Template

  ```xml
  <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:CalendarCore.Controls">

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LABEL.WEEK">
          <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0 4 0 4"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                          <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                     VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                      </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="LBXI.DAY">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 1"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
          <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" />
                      </Border>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                          <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA"/>
                          </Trigger>
                          <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                              <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F1F1F1"/>
                          </Trigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLastMonth}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNextMonth}" Value="True">
                              <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#BBBBBB"/>
                          </DataTrigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:CalendarBox}">
          <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2"/>
          <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource LBXI.DAY}"/>
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 0 0"/>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DDDDDD"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:CalendarBox}">
                      <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                          <Grid>
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <UniformGrid Columns="7">
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="MON" Background="#FFFFEAEA"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="TUE" Background="#FFE8F9FF"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="WED" Background="#FFE1F1C5"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="THU" Background="#FFFFD7D7"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="FRI" Background="#FFE9F9E4"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="SAT" Background="#FFF7F6E3"/>
                                  <Label Style="{StaticResource LABEL.WEEK}" Content="SUN" Background="#FFC4DAE4"/>
                              </UniformGrid>

                              <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                          </Grid>
                      </Border>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
          <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      <UniformGrid Columns="7"/>
                  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
  ```
- MainWindow (.xaml)

  ```xml
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Button x:Name="btnPreview" Content="Preview" Margin="4" Padding="4"/>
          <Button x:Name="btnNext" Content="Next" Margin="4" Padding="4"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <ctrl:CalendarBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="calendar"/>
  </Grid>
  ```
- Code Behind (.cs)

  ```cs
  using System;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Windows;
  using CalendarCore.Enums;
  using CalendarCore.Models;

  namespace CalendarDemo.Basic
  {
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
      {
          private int Year;
          private int Month;

          public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();

              Year = DateTime.Now.Year;
              Month = DateTime.Now.Month;

              Loaded += (s,e)=> Refresh(CalendarMove.None);
              btnPreview.Click += (ps, pe) => Refresh(CalendarMove.Preview);
              btnNext.Click += (ns, ne) => Refresh(CalendarMove.Next);
          }

          private void Refresh(CalendarMove move)
          {
              DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(Year, Month, 1);
              int moveMonth = 0;
              switch (move)
              {
                  case CalendarMove.None: moveMonth = 0; break;
                  case CalendarMove.Preview: moveMonth = -1; break;
                  case CalendarMove.Next: moveMonth = 1; break;
              }

              Year = currentDateTime.AddMonths(moveMonth).Year; 
              Month = currentDateTime.AddMonths(moveMonth).Month;

              calendar.ItemsSource = GenerateCalendar(Year, Month);
          }

          private IEnumerable GenerateCalendar(int year, int month)
          {
              List<DayModel> days = new List<DayModel>();

              // Step 1. Add days of last month.
              AddDaysOfLastMonth(year, month, ref days);

              // Step 2. Add days of current mon.th
              AddDaysOfCurrentMonth(year, month, ref days);

              // Step 3. Add days of next month.
              AddDaysOfNextMonth(year, month, ref days);
              return days;
          }

          private void AddDaysOfLastMonth(int year, int month, ref List<DayModel> days)
          {
              var lastMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddMonths(-1);

              int dayStarting;
              int lastDayOfLastMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month);
              DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = new DateTime(year, month, 1).DayOfWeek;

              switch (firstDayOfWeek)
              {
                  case DayOfWeek.Monday: dayStarting = 0; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: dayStarting = 1; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: dayStarting = 2; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Thursday: dayStarting = 3; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Friday: dayStarting = 4; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Saturday: dayStarting = 5; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Sunday: dayStarting = 6; break;
                  default: dayStarting = 0;break;
              }

              for (int i = 1; i <= dayStarting; i++)
              {
                  days.Add(new DayModel
                  {
                      Date = new DateTime(lastMonth.Year, lastMonth.Month, lastDayOfLastMonth + i - dayStarting),
                      IsLastMonth = true
                  });
              }
          }

          private void AddDaysOfCurrentMonth(int year, int month, ref List<DayModel> days)
          {
              int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
              for (int i = 1; i <= lastDay; i++)
              {
                  days.Add(new DayModel { Date = new DateTime(year, month, i) });
              }
          }

          private void AddDaysOfNextMonth(int year, int month, ref List<DayModel> days)
          {
              var nextMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddMonths(1);
              var lastDayofCurrentMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

              int dayStarting;
              DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = new DateTime(year, month, lastDayofCurrentMonth).DayOfWeek;

              switch (lastDayOfWeek)
              {
                  case DayOfWeek.Monday: dayStarting = 6; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Tuesday: dayStarting = 5; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Wednesday: dayStarting = 4; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Thursday: dayStarting = 3; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Friday: dayStarting = 2; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Saturday: dayStarting = 1; break;
                  case DayOfWeek.Sunday: dayStarting = 0; break;
                  default: dayStarting = 0; break;
              }

              for (int i = 1; i <= dayStarting; i++)
              {
                  days.Add(new DayModel
                  {
                      Date = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, i),
                      IsNextMonth = true
                  });
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Model

  ```cs
  public class DayModel
  {
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }

      public int Year => Date.Year;
      public int Month => Date.Month;
      public int Day => Date.Day;

      public bool IsLastMonth { get; set; }
      public bool IsCurrentMonth { get; set; }
      public bool IsNextMonth { get; set; }
  }
  ```